# php mysql insert into utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, insert

I'm going to insert into some articles in mysql using PHP.

This is phpMyAdmin information:

```
Server: localhost via TCP/IP
Server version: 5.0.85-community-nt
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Here is my table information:

```
Table   Action  Records 1  Type  Collation  Size  Overhead  
article       10 InnoDB utf8_unicode_ci 16.0 KiB - 
1 table(s)  Sum 10 InnoDB utf8_unicode_ci 16.0 KiB 0 B
```

I add

```
<?php header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

in the top  of my php code, add `mysql_query("set names 'utf-8'");` before `mysql_select_db("data",$db1);`

but the data in the mysql is still like

```
piÃ¹ freddi
```

How do I show the data correctly?

Comment: Where do you see data as being incorrect? If it's in some client program or in console, it might be that it is not configured to display Unicode correctly, while the data stored is in fact correct.

Comment: @Mchl, I see it directly in the table of phpMyAdmin

Comment: `utf8` not `utf-8` in set names

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, you are right, it is my mistake. so how to toggle a correct answer to you?

Comment: @yuli: You can't accept a comment as a correct answer. On that note, why do people post correct answers as comments anyways?

Comment: so I only vote a agree ticket for my appreciation.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Get rid of the hyphen. It should be:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: also make sure all your table's collation are 'utf8_unicode_ci' and same for the required field also.

Comment: hi, if I insert germany, italian, frence, spanish, dutch, japanese, rusia. do you think I choose `utf8_unicode_ci` or `utf8_general_ci` be better?

Comment: I would highly recommend unicode. We have used it to insert arabic, english and everything works fine. Unicode cover a greater span and should do you just fine. Although recommend testing all languages first / get some expert advice

Comment: add this code before insert query it works.

Comment: You can do also: $connection->query("SET NAMES utf8"); if you use mysqli_connect.

Answer (score 15):

Use following code for inserting

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");
mysql_query($qry);
```

This is worked fine in my case

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the character encoding on the client as well, use

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: The OP is already doing this via `<?php header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?> `

Comment: You have to specify this on the client that will submit the data that the PHP will get to put into the database. The "header()" php function will set the header of the HTTP response sent out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php 

"header — ===> Send <=== a raw HTTP header"