# php json_encode is returning 0 , zero value sometimes

Tags: php, mysql, json

something is going wrong , im saving json_encode response in mysql db. it sometimes saving `0` value.im 100% sure that my json_encode function does not receive `0` as a parameter because it always get empty array or associated array, so there is no any chance to receive `0` in parameter.

Problem is that why json_encode returns `0` value sometimes.
i have column type `longtext` in db table where im saving its response.
is it issue with character types? like UTF8 or non UTF8?

**Here is a code snippet:**

```
$jsonPayload = [];

if (isset($obj['answer']) && (!empty($obj['answer']) || $obj['answer'] == 0)) {
       $jsonPayload[$form_fields[$i]->id] = $obj;         
}

return json_encode($jsonPayload);
```

Comment: You are using a relational database completely wrong. You don't put an array, or anything encoded into a database. You put each value into their table column. That's what it means to use a relational database.

Comment: var dump the array so we can see it

Comment: `json_encode` doesn't return `0`, but it can return `false`. My bet is you have some non-UTF8 characters in your encode

Comment: according to my investigation its return 0 due to non-UTF8 character. but dont have such character on which i can test either json_encode return 0 on passing non-UTF8 characters or not.
I wants to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
json_encode($jsonPayload,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Probably it will work.

Comment: brother its returning 0, do you think that its character type issue? like UTF8 or non UTF8 characters.

Comment: can you please show print_r($jsonPayload); result?

Comment: no brother, its on live server, i dont know whats comming in payload, but special character can be present in payload, i need such character which return 0 for json_encode

Comment: You can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663255/php-mysql-insert-into-utf-8

Comment: no its not a issue